# QGIS 2.2.0 Valmiera

Tags: qgis, relates

## One to many joins

### Unable to export as WKT geometry

I'm trying to perform a one-to-many join between a postcode dataset (shapefile) and a csv txt dataset of addresses.
I have multiple addresses per postcode, and need to be able to match all of them together.

I have seen various answers where I should export the Postcode dataset to a csv file and join together in LibreOffice etc.
BUT when I try and  "save as"  there is no option for  GEOMETRY AS_WKT !
only AS_XY  etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new field in you data and calculate the WKT into it - it is simple syntax:
 geomToWKT(  $geometry )

However if you have precise keys in both datasets, there should be no problem in creating the 1 - to many join...

Comment: Thanks for that ! Created the WKT attribute just fine. Just got to sort out the join now ....  both tables have a postcode attribution which should join, it'd be far easier to do this in QGIS than export/ import. I read somewhere that gvSIG can do this ?